# How to encode structure changes in XML?

Tags: xml

I have a tree structure that maps quite naturally to XML. However, I would also need to encode **changes** to the tree structure, e.g. moving some element to another place or merging one node into another, so I can update the tree on the target system. Deleting the whole tree and recreating it is no option because of complex data referring to the tree nodes, which have to be treated accordingly.

Of course I have a general idea how to do this, but before I jump right into programming I wanted to ask if there are already exising solutions or best practices for this kind of "update" problems. For me, this seems like a common kind of requirement, but to my surprise I couldn't find anything concerning this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformation) is probably the answer to your question. It describes the transformation between two xml documents.

You would:

- Express your changes using and `xsl` stylesheet
- Test them locally
- Apply xsl stylesheet to the target system

While XPath was my first intention, you'll find some promising but proprietary software alternatives when you search for [`xml structure diff`](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=xml%20structure%20diff&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=L8XYU5gahYnxB6WsgeAN) on google

Comment: The target system needs to "understand" the required changes (Something along the lines: "Oh, now node 73 has a new name and moved below node 23") in order to do its own changes (not necessarily limited to the tree itself), and I don't think this will work with XSLT.

Comment: It can be done using XPath, however it would be hard to craft that xsl manually. Therefore you might have a look into the proprietary tools (at least a look). I expect that they automate most things for you.

Comment: @Landei I've recognized that you accepted my answer. I'm curious how you solution looked like?